# Window Application

Tags: c#-3.0

how to create connection using class file in C# for windows application?... how to develop Data access layer... regarding 3-tire architecture using mysql databases

Comment: Please edit your question so it's a little more specific about what you want to do.  What kind of connection?

Comment: Most implementations have _4_ tires.  (Except motorcycles)